# No CS0184 warning for impossible check

Tags: c#, roslyn, compiler-warnings

Why does testB in [this example](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghglgdgPgAQEwEYCwAoZACBKDsmA3ptmbgCzYCy0MAFAJSnkkbkfYBuEATthGwBebDACmAdxoBPAMIAbCAGclKJgG4Wnbn2zBh2egElq0ozAAuY3gDMIAYzGNxU0wuWqNWzt44B6PwBxMQsBbFkAZQAGFAAOKgB1PhhYAHNsAHsYbAsACyglbHlYMV9yHn4rJQsAQQNBApl3FSRNdm1sMrIAgDkM7AlktMzsvMbi8S6dSrFqgCEDfUa3RRa2jo3O9rIAX0w9jExYK1sHMWwTM0trO0difcxMHBWPFGwQC9NzE9vSjDYDk8kE1VkokPcMAcgA===) not give a "warning CS0184: The given expression is never of the provided ('MyClass2') type" the same way that testA does?

```
class Program
{
    void Main()
    {
        var a = new MyClass1();
        var b = (IMyInterface)new MyClass1();
        
        //Get a CS0184 Warning on this line
        var testA = a is MyClass2;
        
        //No warning on this line
        var testB = b is MyClass2;
                
    }
}

interface IMyInterface
{
}

class MyClass1 : IMyInterface
{
}

class MyClass2
{
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because the type of `b` is `IMyInterface`. The compiler does not analyse the code to find the actual runtime type of the object you assigned to `b`.

It is possible for a variable of type `IMyInterface` to be `is MyClass2`. For example, if `b` refers to an instance of `MyClass3`:

```
class MyClass3: MyClass2, IMyInterface {}
```

Of course, if `MyClass2` is `sealed`, `MyClass3` cannot exist, so `b` can never be `is MyClass2` in that case, and you get the warning as expected.

This is also why it is possible to cast an expression of a non-sealed class type to any interface type, e.g.

```
var a = new MyClass2();
// this compiles, but throws an exception at runtime, of course
var b = (IMyInterface)a;
```

Even if `MyClass2` doesn't implement `IMyInterface`, at runtime it may be referring to some subclass that *does* implement `IMyInterface`.

Comment: Could the analyzer look at every class derived from MyClass2 and see none of them implement the interface?  In other words is the analysis impossible, or is it just not done by the current C# compiler?

Comment: I suppose with use of reflection MyClass3 could be created at run time, leading me to think the check is impossible.

Comment: @innominate227 That's right. In addition, this is just a compiler warning - it probably isn't worth the effort to implement such a check.

Comment: well it would have saved me 8 hours of debugging if the compiler had warned me about a bad check so worth it to me